# ¿Cómo cambiar los sliders automáticamente en un intervalo de tiempo?

Tags: javascript

Soy algo nuevo en el mundo de la programación y tengo un problema con **JavaScript** que no se resolver. Estoy tratando de *crear unos sliders* que pasen automáticamente en un intervalo de tiempo y a su vez que los pueda pasar manualmente.

Este es mi código

```js
const sliders = [...document.querySelectorAll(".slider__body")];
const arrowBefore = document.querySelector("#before");
const arrowAfter = document.querySelector("#after");
let value;
arrowBefore.addEventListener("click", ()=>changePosition(-1));
arrowAfter.addEventListener("click", ()=>changePosition(1));
function changePosition(change){
    const currentElement = Number(document.querySelector(".slider__body--show").dataset.id);
    value = currentElement;
    value+= change;
    if(value === 0 || value == sliders.length+1){
        value = value === 0 ? sliders.length : 1;
    }
    sliders[currentElement-1].classList.toggle("slider__body--show");
    sliders[value-1].classList.toggle("slider__body--show");
}
```

Pensé en poner un código como el siguiente, pero no funcionó:

```
function cambiarImagenes(){
    if(sliders.length < 4){
        sliders++;
    }
}
setInterval(cambiarImagenes, 3000);
```

También intenté esto y no funciono:

```
setInterval(changePosition, 3000);
```

Comment: Cuando ocurre el evento click llamas a changePosition... cuando ocurra el evento "intervalo", haz la misma llamada

Comment: Ya intente hacerlo de esa forma y no funciono. Cambia el contenido y se queda todo en blanco. Este fue el código que utilice: `setInterval(changePosition, 3000);`

Comment: Claro, así llamas a changePosition sin parámetros